# How to read data from RFIDControllerMfrc522

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, rfid

I'm trying to find substitution for my rfid card. The current script is made in Python and is using SimpleMFRC522 library which is working perfectly. However, I want to use C#.

I found one library **Unosquare.RaspberryIO.Peripherals**, but I can't find good documentation. The function below is returning data 4, which is not the data that is written on the card.

If there is any other good RFID library, let me know. Thank you in advance!

```
Pi.Init<BootstrapWiringPi>();
var _reader = new RFIDControllerMfrc522();

while (true)
{
    if (_reader.DetectCard() == RFIDControllerMfrc522.Status.AllOk)
    {
        var uidResponse = _reader.ReadCardUniqueId();
        if (uidResponse.Status == RFIDControllerMfrc522.Status.AllOk)
        {
            var cardUid = uidResponse.Data;
            _reader.SelectCardUniqueId(cardUid);

            try
            {
                if (_reader.AuthenticateCard1A(cardUid, 7) == RFIDControllerMfrc522.Status.AllOk)
                {
                    var a = _reader.CardReadData(0);
                    foreach (var item in a.Data)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _reader.ClearCardSelection();
            }
        }
    }
}
```